# Java i can not initalize reference varibale in subclass because "VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token"

Tags: java, oop, strategy-pattern

I have created an interface Flyable and the class FlyableWithWing implementing this interface

```
public interface Flyable {
    void fly();
}
```

```
public class FlyWithWings implements Flyable {
    @Override
    public void fly() {
        System.out.println("This animal flyies with wings");
    }
}
```

I have created a supers class Duck and subclass MallarDuck. Class Duck holds a reference to an object type Flyable.

```
public class Duck {
    Flyable flyBehaviour;

    void perfomFly() {
        flyBehaviour.fly();
    }
}
```

I tried to initilize varibale flyBehaviour in subclass MallarDuck with Flyable object. but i get an error "VariableDeclaratorId expected after this token".

```
public class MallarDuck extends Duck {
    flyBehaviour = new FlyWithWings();
}
```

Comment: *flyBehaviour = new FlyWithWings();* is outside of a method

Comment: Move ```flyBehaviour = new FlyWithWings();``` into a constructor